# Select the same random item in two different arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Say you were to select a random song from an array.

```js
var songs = ["song1","song2","song3"]
var randSong = songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)];
```

Would it be possible to also select that element from a different array? 
Like this:

```js
var time = ["song1time","song2time","song3time"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value of `Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length)` in a variable and pass its value to both of array.

```js
var songs = ["song1","song2","song3"]
var time = ["song1time","song2time","song3time"]
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);

var randSong = songs[index];
var timeValue = time[index];

console.log(randSong, timeValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the two arrays have the same song order then yes.

store the random number in a separate variable so that it can be reused.

```
var randNum = Math.random()
```

Then replace the random generator in randSong with the random variable

```
var songs = ["song1","song2","song3"]
var randSong = songs[Math.floor( randNum * songs.length)];
```

Then you can reuse it with you time array.

```
var time = ["song1time","song2time","song3time"]
var randTime = time[Math.floor( randNum * time.length)];
```

If the two arrays don't have the same song order then you'll have to switch to objects instead of arrays.

```
var songs = {
  1:"song1",
  2:"song2",
  3:"song3"
}
```

If you randomize to get a song like so:

```
var randomSong = Object.keys(songs)[Math.floor( Math.random() * Object.keys(songs).length)];
```

Then you can identify the song you want with your randomSong variable. Let's say you had another object where the order was different but the keys correspond to the same song...

```
var otherSongs = {
  1:"song1",
  3:"song3",
  2:"song2",
}
```

Identify the song you want with your randomSong variable like so:

```
otherSongs[randomSong]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to check the arrays are the same size otherwise timeValue may be undefined if songs had more than 3 elements.

```
var songs = ["song1","song2","song3"]
var time = ["song1time","song2time","song3time"]
if(time.length === songs.length){
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
    var randSong = songs[index];
    var timeValue = time[index];
    console.log(randSong, timeValue);
 }
```